# i cant send the push notification through FCM with android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

i have created a basic activity where, when we press a button then it should send a notification to every phone.But i am not getting the notification ... there are no errors showing in android studio.

Please suggest what changes should be made to make it work!!

***OnCreate()*** function

```
        Button=findViewById(R.id.sendNotice);
        mRequestQue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);//created a request queue

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");

        Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PushNotification();
            }
        });
```

***PushNotification()*** function

```
private void PushNotification() {
        JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            mainObj.put("to","/topics/"+"news");

            JSONObject notificationObj = new JSONObject();//now json obj ready

            notificationObj.put("title","any title");
            notificationObj.put("body","any body");
            mainObj.put("notification",notificationObj);

            //create json req

            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                    mainObj,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            Log.d("MUR", "onResponse: ");
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("MUR", "onError: "+error.networkResponse);
                }
            }
            ){
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> header=new HashMap<>();
                    header.put("content-type","application/json");
                    header.put("authorization","key=AAAAfIXwoyU:APA91bHs2xzjOJU8QzavKILYCe7ziVSvbP3biSUs25Mww1dyZtKtn96rvEppGFMBb4bWnrT-9rv5nY6TAuBTakWA79pGkP7uEI50bJISWx10DfOCfEB0mfPbTtrHZiLs4x8sGx-xQg5s");
                    return header;
                }
            };
            mRequestQue.add(request);
        }
        catch (JSONException e)

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Edit : ---
Added build Gradle file :-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.getlocation"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Toast is running but no notification is coming

Comment: What is `URL`?   Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Firebase's docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages)

When your app in the foreground, you have to override onMessageReceived method to get notification

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, 
        notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

}